# Python connect to MySQL and MariaDB from same application?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector

How can I connect to both MySQL and MariaDB from the same Python 3.6+ application? The application is installed on RHEL8, same issue seems to exist on Ubuntu.

Due to security vulnerabilities, I have to use MySQL client 8.0.30 or later

mysql.connector with client 8.0.30 can not connect to MariaDB (charset error, known issue, no listed workaround)

Mariadb can not be installed alongside MySQL due to package conflicts:

```
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.6.12-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-common-8.0.30-1.module+el8.6.0+16523+5cb0e868.x86_64
```

Comment: Are these existing databases? Or are you creating two new databases? One with MariaDB and the other with MySQL.

Comment: These are existing external databases backing third party software. My application is an ETL system populating a data warehouse.